# Solidity 0.5 Truffle Compile Error

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-compile

I just upgraded my code to Solidity 0.5 and am trying to use the truffle framework with it. I did update my code in Remix and installed truffle@beta so that it can use v5.

The problem I have is that I am unable to compile my code with truffle. I get this error message:

> UnimplementedFeatureError: Encoding type "struct
>   Contract.MyStruct memory" not yet implemented.

What could the problem be as the code does work properly with remix?

Edit: The line of code I typed that gets me to this error after I access my contract folder via the terminal is:

```
truffle compile
```

It doesn't give me a line number for where the error is from in my contract but I have functions that return a struct which with Solidity 0.5 need the memory keyword.

Comment: Ever occurred to you that you should post the line of code which yields this error?

Comment: So I manage to fix it. After googling the problem again I found these two links: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/63149/nested-structs-that-are-part-of-a-mapping-broken-in-solidity-0-5-0/63152#63152 and https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/63149/nested-structs-that-are-part-of-a-mapping-broken-in-solidity-0-5-0/63152#63152. 
The problem ended up coming from having functions that an inherited contract will be using that returned a struct. 
I just deleted these functions for now and it seems to work.

Comment: @Emul - Please add this as an answer (and accept it - though you might have to wait 48 hours to accept your own answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem. 
After googling the problem again I found these two links: [Nested structs that are part of a mapping broken in Solidity 0.5.0?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/63149/nested-structs-that-are-part-of-a-mapping-broken-in-solidity-0-5-0/63152#63152)
and 
[Nested structs that are part of a mapping broken in Solidity 0.5.0?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/63149/nested-structs-that-are-part-of-a-mapping-broken-in-solidity-0-5-0/63152#63152)
which sent me in the right direction.

The problem ended up coming from having functions that an inherited contract will be using that returned a struct (which now with Solidity 0.5 must be in memory). I just deleted these functions for now and inputted the information directly in the inherited contract. It now works.